# Attribute is not able to be selected

Tags: magento-1.7, promotions, cart-rule

I am trying to use newsletter promotion extension provided at GIT

https://gist.github.com/drewgillson/3009236

Ref for creating promotion condition: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ca/2010/04/create-bulk-discount-rules.html

Here I am trying following code for condition

```
   $conditions['1--2'] = Array
(
'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',
'value' => 0,
'aggregator' => 'all',
'new_child' => '', 
);

$conditions['1--2--1'] = Array
(
'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
'attribute' => 'special_price',
'operator' => '<',
'value' => '0',
);
```

Above code is not working if I try valid attribute code ( second condition ) like 'special_price', 'sku' or 'price'

But if I misspell attribute then it generate promotion rule only attribute is missing from it.

[image]

I don't know why attribute is not selected except everything else....

Comment: Make sure the attributes you are using are available for rule creation. Edit the attribute and set the field `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` to `Yes`. A reindex may be required after.

Comment: yes special price attribute is already in promo rule. I can see it in drop-down in conditions, if check manually.

Its quite strange behavior if I try `special_price` it show error and do not create rule at all, but If I enter **incorrect attribute code** like `specialprice` it create rule and as show in screen shot...

Comment: What error do you get? And can you post the full code so I can test it?

Comment: Its only said there was problem creating coupon. 
I am trying to figure out it. 

If I remove this second condition and use only first condition ie subtotal condition it works fine see screen shot.

Comment: The error message is a general one. You should see more details in var/log if you have error logging enabled.

Comment: no error in log.

Comment: I tried the code from the 'gist' you posted, with your conditions with a minor change. Instead of `$rule->setWebsiteIds(1);` I used `$rule->setWebsiteIds(array(1));`. And it worked perfectly.

Comment: wow great man its works perfect. 
How you can get that? 
you are really genius, I never though about that.

thanks man.

Comment: write it in answer I wanna mark is as Solved ...

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Comment: Please explain me How did u get it exactly? 
What is logic behind array(1)?

Comment: The best way to see how to create something by code is to see how the code in the controller looks like and try to reproduce it. For your case, when saving a rule in the backend the websites for the rule are sent as an array.

Comment: By adding the $websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection(); $websiteIds = array(); foreach ($websites as $website) { $websiteIds[] = $website->getId(); }
$rule->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds); is not solving the problem. I have done all the things which you have described here ,but still i am facing the problem.

Comment: Hi Webtechnology Codes, you just need to replace `1` by `array(1)` in short `$rule->setWebsiteIds(1);` replace this line to `$rule->setWebsiteIds(array(1));`. No need to add websiteid array what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code from the 'gist' you posted, with your conditions with a minor change. Instead of

```
$rule->setWebsiteIds(1);
```

I used

```
$rule->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
```

And it worked perfectly.